# Class multiple inheritance in many versions in Python

Tags: python, oop

Is there a way to use multiple version of a class, each version inheriting from a subclass of the same class.
Here is a sample of the code

```py
    class AI(Character):
        def __init__(self, name) -> None:
            super().__init__(name)

    class AI_easy(AI):
        def __init__(name):
            super().__init__(name)

    class AI_hard(AI):
        def __init__(name):
            super().__init__(name)

    class Pokemon():
        def __init__(self, name) -> None:
            self.name = name

    class PokemonWild(Pokemon,IA):
        def __init__(self, name) -> None:
            super().__init__(name)
```

Here i need to have PokemonWild with AI_hard and AI_easy. Is it mandatory to define these classes?
Can I choose from what class it inherit with a parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by using something without defining it?

Comment: I mean by not having PokemonWild_easy and PokemonWild_hard classes and choosing from what class you inherit with a parameter

Comment: I suppose it depends on how you plan to use the AI part, which you have not made clear.  For example, if you just had an AI object as an instance variable in a Pokemon object, it would be easy.

Comment: `PokemonWild = type('PokemonWild', (Pokemon, AI_easy if easy else AI_hard), {})`. The value of `easy` determines the second parent class.

Comment: It sounds, though, like you want *instances* of one class or the other without pre-defining both classes ahead of time. You can do that, kind of, but class will be defined as a side effect one way or another, and then you run the risk of defining the same class multiple times (with each class being distinct but essentially identical to the others, making for hard-to-diagnose bugs) unless you are very careful.

Comment: Using inheritance is not the right approach here

Comment: ok thank you I will edit the question. Character is an abstract class with the method play_turn. I will only use PokemonWild in a class Combat and use the method play_turn of AI_hard or AI_easy depending on user choice.

Comment: Thank you.
@juanpa.arrivillaga what would be the right approach ?